# Is there any way to extract text from the file and make a dictionary from it?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a file:

> Dog['bark','eat','fly']
>
> Cat['meow', 'eat ', 'fly']

There are 2x'\n' between them. I need to extract them and convert to a dictionary.
When I am trying to read a text from there by using readlines, I get list of these items like that:

> "Dog['bark','eat','fly']\n", '\n', "Cat['meow', 'eat ', 'fly']\n", '\n']

And I want to get a dictionary like that... animal[dog] = ['bark','eat','fly'], and the same with the cat. What should I use? `maybe split them up or anything else.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
 text = file.readlines()
 text.replace('\n','')
And I stuck on this point.

Comment: Maybe I should use regex in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. It requires a bit of string manipulation, but I think it should suit your needs.

```
animals = {}
with open("file.txt") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        if (line != "\n"):
            key = line.rstrip().split('[')[0]
            val = (line.rstrip().split('[')[1][:-1]).replace("'", "").replace(" ", "").split(',')
            animals[key] = val

print(animals)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses regex:

```
import json
import re

s = '''Dog['bark','eat','fly']

Cat['meow', 'eat ', 'fly']'''

dictionary = {}
for line in s.split('\n'):
    if line:
        search = re.search('^([a-zA-Z]+)(\[.+\])$', line, re.IGNORECASE)
        if search:
            key, arr = search.groups()
            dictionary[key] = json.loads(arr.replace('\'', '"'))

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'Cat': ['meow', 'eat ', 'fly'], 'Dog': ['bark', 'eat', 'fly']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

text = """
Dog['bark','eat','fly']

Cat['meow', 'eat ', 'fly']
"""
animals = {}
for line in text.splitlines():
    if line:
        a, b = line.split("[")
        b = "[" + b
        animals[a] = ast.literal_eval(b)
print(animals)
# {'Dog': ['bark', 'eat', 'fly'], 'Cat': ['meow', 'eat ', 'fly']}
```

Comment: There is no need to use `ast.literal_eval` here. One could just remove the `'` through replace function.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to convert the string to a better format:

```py
animalValues=["Dog['bark','eat','fly']\n", '\n', "Cat['meow', 'eat ','fly']\n", '\n']
animalValues=[i.replace("\n","") for i in animalValues if i != "\n"]
```

Then, we convert the list into a dict:

```py
animalDict={i.split("[")[0]: [p.replace("'","") for p in i.split("[")[1].split("]")[0].split(",")] for i in animalValues}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more robust solution, since the input is actually valid Python code with several named objects sliced with tuples, you can use `ast.parse` to parse the input into AST nodes and iterate over the name-tuple pairs like this:

```
import ast
s = '''Dog['bark','eat','fly']

Cat['meow', 'eat ', 'fly']'''
{n.value.value.id: [i.value for i in n.value.slice.value.elts] for n in ast.parse(s).body}
```

This returns:

```
{'Dog': ['bark', 'eat', 'fly'], 'Cat': ['meow', 'eat ', 'fly']}
```